# Can not find schema when using ConvertJSONToAvro in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using InferAvroSchema and ConvertJSONToAvro to convet json file to avro file.

This is `InferAvroSchema` config:

[image]

and this is `ConvertJSONToAvro` config:

But it always complains `Can not find schema`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I should check the `flowfile-attribute` option:

[image]